# Auto-complete overwrite existing code in VS Community 2022

Tags: python, visual-studio, autocomplete

I have an annoying problem in VS Community 2022.

When I go to add text and tap **Enter** or **Tab** buttons, autocomplete likes to overwrite some of the existing code.

[image: Auto commplete]

The result :

[image: The result]

I don't want it to automatically delete the text `range( )` before and after what I am auto-completing.

Thank you in advance for helping me.